# How to get firestore timestamp

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to get the timestamp of a document that I created in firestore, but what I get is this:

[image]

**myService.ts**

```
getDomiciliarios() {
this.domiciliarios = this.afs.collection('domiciliarios').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Domiciliario;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    const date = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    return { id, ...data, date };
  });
});

return this.domiciliarios;
}
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
const domiciliarios = this.fs.getDomiciliarios()
  .subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data, date => date);
}
```

**myComponent.html**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="fecha">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fecha </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let domiciliario"> {{ domiciliario.date }} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

How can I print that timestamp, should I have previously created it?

Comment: Try using **date** pipe as `<mat-cell *matCellDef="let domiciliario"> {{ domiciliario.date | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy' }} </mat-cell>`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I get the following error `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'DatePipe'`

Comment: Before feeding to `const date=` try `new Date(timestampvalue)`

Answer (score 23):

IF you want the date value of `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` you can use `.toDate()`.
See [FireStore Timesteamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp/). In your case it will be `domiciliario.date.toDate()` in your template.

Answer (score 19):

I think you are using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` the wrong way: as the documentation states, `firebase.firestore.FieldValue` methods return "values that can be used **when writing** document fields with set() or update()".
(See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue)

You are using the `serverTimestamp()` method while reading the data.

You should use it **when you create** the records in the database, as you mention at the end of your question.

EDIT:
Do as follow:

```
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
docRef.update({ updatedAt: timestamp });
```

You can then query like

```
collectionRef.orderBy('updatedAt').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            ...
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

*The above code is pure JavaScript and you may adapt it to angular and type script but the philosophy is the same.*

Comment: This timestamp is not generated automatically like the ID? If not, then how can I add that timestamp in Firestore?

Comment: Thanks I added a variable with `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp ();` and this added a field with the date in Firestore. I will respond with this.

Comment: @PacoZevallos Cool! :-) If you now query ordered on this value you should get what you are looking for

Comment: I should mention that `new Date ()` also works for me, I do not understand what the difference is with `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp ()` when creating a timestamp but it also works for me.

Comment: @PacoZevallos `new Date()` is the current timestamp of your client machine (the user's browser) while `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp ()` is the timestamp of the Firebase server

Comment: Oh that's a very significant difference then, since `new Date` can be manipulated and modified by the user, whereas `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp ()` does not. This is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169783/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-paco-zevallos).

Comment: has this changed to "FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),"? because I am getting instance of FirebaseFirestore instead of firebase.firestore? Kindly confirm or suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh AFAI it is still the same syntax **in JavaScript**.

Comment: Could you please suggest me for flutter / dart for the same? Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh See https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue-class.html

Answer (score 18):

If you want the current Date as a timestamp you can use the following

**For Firebase Functions**

```
import admin = require('firebase-admin');

const todayAsTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

**For local projects**

```
import { Timestamp } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

const myTimestampAsDate = Timestamp.now()
```

Comment: This returns user's local date time. If user's date/time is wrong, you will get wrong date/time

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Renaud who put emphasis on where I was implementing the timestamp, it should be when creating a record in Firestore. In my case I am working with a formGroup, then the code would look something like this:

```
forma: FormGroup;

constructor( fb: FormBuilder) { 
  this.forma = fb.group ({
    field1: [ ''],
    field2: [ ''],
    ...
    myDate: [ firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() ],
  });
}
```

This alternative also works but remember that it is the current time of the client's computer (user's browser).

```
forma: FormGroup;

constructor( fb: FormBuilder) { 
  this.forma = fb.group ({
    field1: [ ''],
    field2: [ ''],
    ...
    myDate: [ new Date() ],
  });
}
```