# Unsupported field value: a function (found in field creationTime)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

*user-profile.ts*

```
export interface UserProfile {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    phone?: string;
    creationTime?: any;
}
```

*service.ts*

```
async signUp(name: string, email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const user: firebase.auth.UserCredential = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      const userProfileDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserProfile> = this.fireStore.doc(`userProfiles/${user.user.uid}`);
      const userProfile: UserProfile = {
        id: user.user.uid,
        email: email,
        creationTime: firebase.firestore.Timestamp,
        name: name
      };
      await userProfileDocument.set(userProfile);
    } catch (error) {
    }
  }
```

One error on console:

> [2019-02-28T08:01:58.804Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.8.3):
>   The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true and you no
>   longer need to explicitly set it. In a future release, the setting
>   will be removed entirely and so it is recommended that you remove it
>   from your firestore.settings() call now.

This is the next error:

> FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid
>   data. Unsupported field value: a function (found in field
>   creationTime)
>       at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:77381:28)
>       at ParseContext.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.ParseContext.createError
>   (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:96125:16)
>       at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseScalarValue
>   (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:96467:27)
>       at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseData
>   (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:96338:29)
>       at http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:96354:41
>       at forEach (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:77483:13)
>       at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseObject
>   (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:96353:13)
>       at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseData
>   (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:96312:25)
>       at UserDataConverter.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.UserDataConverter.parseSetData
>   (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:96177:31)
>       at DocumentReference.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.DocumentReference.set
>   (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:97049:45)

Comment: not sure why you are setting a class in creationTIme property... https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

Comment: I have done like so: https://github.com/javebratt/master-firestore-fit-coach/blob/master/src/app/services/client.service.ts#L49 @SurajRao He is a firebase Master. maybe I have applied it wrongly no?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012438/how-to-get-firestore-timestamp seems to say the same as the answer.. So not sure what is happening in your github link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do as follows:

*1st error:* https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1993#issuecomment-456481677

*2nd Error:*

```
  const userProfile: UserProfile = {
    id: user.user.uid,
    email: email,
    creationTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    name: name
  };
```

As explained in the doc, [`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.serverTimestamp) will return a "sentinel" object that you use when building the object to be written to Firestore. It will indicate to the server that it should replace it with an actual Timestamp.

Comment: Now no run time error and above works. But do you know why this console error? `[2019-02-28T08:39:02.572Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.8.3): 
  The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true and you no
  longer need to explicitly set it. In a future release, the setting
  will be removed entirely and so it is recommended that you remove it
  from your firestore.settings() call now.`

Comment: Before 5.8.3 you had to manually set the `timestampsInSnapshots` setting to `true` with `const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
admin.firestore().settings(settings);`. The information message you mention just indicates that you don't need to do that anymore.

Comment: I didn't set anything. So where should I look at this setting?

Comment: This works for me: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1993#issuecomment-456481677 Thanks.

Comment: The message says that you don't need to add `timestampsInSnapshots: true` in your `firestore.settings()` call anymore. So if you didn't call `firestore.settings()`, you don't need to do anything.